# Google Translate URL on website

Tags: html, google-translate

I have problem with Google translate urls... On my website I put 3 linked flags - one in my language, others in english and german. Strukture of my flags:

```
<div class="language">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.pl/"><img src="img/pl.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/translate_c?langpair=pl|en&u=http://www.mywebsite.pl/"><img src="img/en.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/translate_c?langpair=pl|de&u=http://www.mywebsite.pl/"><img src="img/de.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

When I translate website first time - everything is OK. But when I click flag on "translated" website Google wants to translate url from href, not my url... And I get error "URL is invalid"... Any solutions?

I would be glad for help! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a image for show me? But 2 links its ok for me, i copy and paste the link in my browser.

Comment: URL to my webiste: http://www.uniteq.pl Try translate to english and after that to german - you will see error... ;(

Comment: Thank you, see this https://translate.google.com/manager/website/add

Comment: But if I want to use flags, not google select??

Comment: I will search for you and return.